# Why does xcode ignore a symbolically linked app icon in the asset catalog source?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the following structure in my iOS Project source folder:

```
resources:
ios/ mac/

resources/ios:
Images.xcassets/         Info.plist               LaunchScreen.storyboard

resources/ios/Images.xcassets:
Contents.json            LaunchImage.launchimage/ AppIcon.appiconset/
```

Everything works fine. If I replace the directory `AppIcon.appiconset` with a symbolic link to a directory with the exact same content, then when I open Images.xcassets in Xcode it shows only LaunchImage and I get a build error that no icon named AppIcon could be found.

This appears to be an Xcode issue. Is it a bug or by design? If the latter, is there a way around it? I really don't want to have multiple copies of these images in the sources for multiple apps.

I can't use hard links because the code is in a git repo so anything other than the original repo would end up with multiple copies on checkout.

Answer (score 0):

If Xcode refuses to copy resources from symbolic, there is probably no way to do this. However, if you want to strictly keep the icons synchronized, you can use a custom shell script phase in your project, which copies the image assets from the macOS folder to the iOS folder.

Just another, even simpler solution could separation the images into special and common icons, and sharing the complete 'common' asset catalog in both targets.

Comment: Thanks @macmoonshine. I began with the common asset catalog approach. I tried symbolic links instead because I want an app's resources to be gathered in a single resource folder to make the source code easier to understand.

Comment: I thin the common asset catalog will be a good choice, because it's intention is obvious for other programmers or later reading. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create `AppIcon.appiconset` as a regular directory and put symlinks inside to each of the shared `Contents.json` and `png` files. This requires more symlinks but does centralize the image storage.